# Open new window in asp.net VB

Tags: asp.net, window.open

I'm a noob progammer that is working on something for our company.  I'm working on a Quiz engine for training.  I have some sample code that is about 90% built.  I just need to tweak a few things.  Here's what I'm working on.

THis is built in ASP.net with VB.  I have a set of questions that I"m pulling from a database (using the built-in SQLDataSource binding).  Currently what it does is pull the question, you select the answer, and click Next.  It then pulls the next question in the list and so forth....till the end.  The Database contains a column that indicates what the correct answer is.  When you click next, it compairs your answer to the correct answer, stores it, then continues to the next question.  At the end, it spits out your correct answers and incorrect answers.

However, this is what I want to do.  When the user selects an answer and clicks next, it immediately opens up a small new window (not a pop-up, but a window on the same page) that immediately "grades" that question and in that window, displays whether it's correct..something like this:

```
If selected answer = correctAnswer then
 "That is correct"
Else
 "THat is not correct.  The correct answer is B"
End if
```

The new window will only contain an "OK" button in the bottom corner.  When the OK is pressed, it closes that new window and processes the rest of what the "next" button is programmed to do.  Here is the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="buttonNext" runat="server" Text="Next" />&nbsp;</td>
```

Here is the Questions.aspx.VB code to go along with that:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles buttonNext.Click


    ' Save off previous answers
    Dim dr As System.Data.DataRowView
    dr = CType(questionDetails.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView)

    ' Create Answer object to save values
    Dim a As Answer = New Answer()
    a.QuestionID = dr("QuestionOrder").ToString()
    a.CorrectAnswer = dr("CorrectAnswer").ToString()
    a.UserAnswer = answerDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString()

    Dim al As ArrayList
    al = CType(Session("AnswerList"), ArrayList)
    al.Add(a)

    Session.Add("AnswerList", al)

    If questionDetails.PageIndex = questionDetails.PageCount - 1 Then
        ' Go to evaluate answers
        Response.Redirect("results.aspx")
    Else
        questionDetails.PageIndex += 1
    End If

    If questionDetails.PageIndex = questionDetails.PageCount - 1 Then
        buttonNext.Text = "Finished"
    End If

End Sub
```

If you are able to provide the code I need, that will be helpful. Thanks in advance for the help.

Tim

Comment: you need to rethink your process a little, two main reasons
1. this will make the quiz far to easy
2. the user will have to answer the question, click next, see if they got it right, then click next again or some other button to get the next question

if you really want to do this then i suggest you look at using a custom validator, but if you do no one will ever 'fail' the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly straight forward. As you have already retrieved the correct answer there is no need to do another call.

On your page you need to create a  where you want the grading and OK button to live.
Something like this would suffice:

```
<div id="gradeWindow" runat="server" visible="false">
<asp:label id="gradeLabel" runat="server" text="" />
<asp:button id="gradeOK" runat="server" text="OK" onclick="gradeOK_Clicked" />
</div>
```

Then modify your function to look like this

```
Session.Add("AnswerList", al)

If String.Compare(a.UserAnswer, a.CorrectAnswer) = 0 then
    gradeLabel.Text = "That is correct"
Else
    gradeLabel.Text = "That is not correct.  The correct answer is " + a.CorrectAnswer
EndIf

gradeWindow.Visible = true

End Sub

Protected Sub gradeOK_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
If questionDetails.PageIndex = questionDetails.PageCount - 1  
  Then                                                               
  Response.Redirect("results.aspx") 
Else                                
  questionDetails.PageIndex += 1                            
End If                                                    
If questionDetails.PageIndex = questionDetails.PageCount - 1 
  Then                                
  buttonNext.Text = "Finished"                            
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for.  Except, how do you get the "That is correct" or "that is incorrect" to show in its own small window that pops up?  I'd like it to do that if possible.

Comment: Sorry I thought you said in your initial post that you didn't want a popup window. That is why I used a div?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  Actually, I've changed it a little bit.  I've included a window.open statement to open this quiz in a new window.  However on this new window, I'd still like a "popup" type window, but as part of the current page (not it's own window) When this window opens, it will dispaly correct or not correct, with an "OK" button, that on click, will close that small popup window and go to the next question.

Comment: In that case the best way to approach it would be to use the ModalPopup control available as part of the AJAX toolkit.

Download the AJAX Toolkit, install it, then add a ModalPopupExtender to the page. You will also need to add a ScriptManager. Then, from your code behind, call the modalpopup.show() function. On your modal popup, have your result and 'OK' button, then upon click of ok tell it to close the modal popup and go to the next question.

I can write more code if you really require...

Comment: I appreciate your help. I've actually never used AJAX or ModalPopups before. I did go and download the AJAX Toolkit and added it. It looks like you apply this extender to the current button already there, so the "Next" button.  I've never worked with these before.  If you wouldn't mind adjusting my code above that you replied to with what needs to be there.  THanks a bunch.